# how to assign int to an object of a class

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to do this;

```
int number = 1;

Class name = new Class();
```

Is there any way that I could assign the name object to number 1?, so that I could use methods of name object by typing,

```
'1. ~~~'
```

instead of `'name. ~~~'`.

What I am trying to do is, the program is going to ask User to put in 'int', and if User put in '1', then User gets to use an object that is assigned to int '1'.
But I don't know how to do that.

1 to this object,

2 to another object,

3.. and so on..

Comment: No. You cannot do that.

Comment: So what would be the best way to what I am trying to do..?
for example, in Main, I created 'dog' Object and 'cat' Object. 
User is going to type 1 or 2 and the object is going to be called depending on the number. What would be the best way to do that..?

Comment: Note: `int` is a primitive. You cannot call methods on it. `Integer` you can, but that doesn't help you here

Comment: You would assign your input to a shared implementation of `Pet`. That is *polymorphism*

Comment: @cricket_007 Could you please explain a bit more with Pet example if you don't mind..?

Comment: `Pet p = new Pet(scanner.next("Please input a pet"))` ... You type "dog"... `System.out.print(p.speak())` would print "woof". Or something to that effect

Comment: In any case, what you are asking sounds like a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit] your post to describe the actual requirements you are trying to solve as a [mcve]

Comment: Oh, that is something I didn't know. I will check and edit to clear my question and get a better answer. Thank you for your advise!, @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't (assign "simple types" to "objects").

But what is possible and matches your request/description best, is:

```
/*java.lang.*/Integer number = 1;
//!
/*java.lang.*/Object obj = number;
```